# Timeout in JedisPool definition

Tags: redis, jedis

While defining a jedisPool object I used the following function and parameters as mentioned [here](https://github.com/redis/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/JedisPool.java).

```
public JedisPool(final GenericObjectPoolConfig<Jedis> poolConfig, final String host, int port,
      int timeout, final String password, final int database) {
    this(poolConfig, host, port, timeout, password, database, null);
  }
```

Everything except for timeout is explanatory. What does `timeout` stand for?

In the other function definitions, we could find parameters like `connectionTimeout`, `soTimeout`, and `infiniteSoTimeout`. If anyone could direct me to any resources that would be much appreciated. I couldn't find these in the official [jedis page](https://github.com/redis/jedis/wiki).

Answer (score 2):

The single `timeout` parameter represents same value for both `connectionTimeout` and `soTimeout`.

In such case `infiniteSoTimeout` is defaulted to `0` (zero, representing indefinite time).